# Encryption / Decryption of app.config sections using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider

Tags: c#, configuration, encryption, rsa

During the installation of our program we run this method to encrpyt sections of the app.config:

```
// Get the application configuration file.
Configuration config =
      ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Define the Rsa provider name.
const string provider = "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider";

// Get the section to protect.
ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.ConnectionStrings;

if (connStrings != null)
{
    if (!connStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        if (!connStrings.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
        {
            // Protect the section.
            connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);

            connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine so far. But if I run this program, we encounter of several machines the following error "Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: **The RSA key container could not be opened**".

Of course I searched and found [this help](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303142036/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mosharaf/archive/2005/11/17/protectedconfiguration.aspx), but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the OS on failing machines? Maybe it could be UAC+Elevation problem. Any information about that machines would be good.

Comment: Maybe a good direction to go. Currently known are Vista, W7 and Server 2008.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into similar issues while debugging within Visual Studio 2010 on Win 7 with UAC set to it's default protection.

In order for me to get around this issue, I had to run Visual Studio as the Administrator ("Run as Administrator").

I had the same issue with trying to run the aspnet_regiis.exe  to encrypt the  section of my web.config. If I didn't run the commandline/console "as Administrator" I would get a commandline error that was even more cryptic: "Object already exists."

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Reason is those machines working have `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` setup in their **machine.config**. Those not working, don't have it - *just manually add it for those machines*.

I imagine that's one of the steps **aspnet_regiis.exe** does. I can't imagine you want to run that on all client machines.

**UPDATE**

OK, I have made the main part of the error in bold in your question - you are right it is a different issue. It is a *security* issue. If you look at the location **C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys** or **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys** depending the operating system, you see a number of files. Your process does have access to the folder so just give files access to the whole folder for the identity of the application or a particular file (timestamp will tell you if you have created it).

Comment: Nope. I checked it on a machine that was crashing - the machine.config contained the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.

Comment: Impossible, not with exact same name. Check the name and make sure it is the same name.

Comment: Checked it twice - definitely the same sections and even the content is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got this on an app.config that was running on a Windows Server set up as a SQL Server. It did not have IIS installed. The machine.config file listed RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider as the default, but when we looked in the two folders mentioned by Aliostad above the folders were empty.There were no keys installed. We used the aspnet_regiis tool to create a custom key. then we used it to grant access to the identity the batch job runs under. All of this was running cmd.exe and aspnet_regiis As Administrator.